# placeholder in select not showing when using formControlName

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, bootstrap-4, angular8

I have a `select` that contains a form control name, when I use

```
<option value = "" selected disabled> Select </option>
```

with `reactForms` it does not display the `placeholder` before the user selects

HTML

```html
<form [formGroup]="formEndereco">
  <select formControlName="parentesco" id="parentesco" class="form-control input-lg" matInput>
    <option value="" selected="selected">Selecione</option>
    <option *ngFor="let itemParentesco of parentescos" [ngValue]="itemParentesco.name">
      {{itemParentesco.name }}</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

TYPE SCRIPT

```js
  gerarFormGroupEndereco() {
    this.formEndereco = this.formBuilder.group({
      parentesco: [],
      estado: [[Validators.required]]
  
    });
  }
```

When using `formControlName` in select 
[image]

When remove`formControlName` in select

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rendered `<select>` is showing blank because in your formGroup, `parentesco` is initiated without a value, which is treated as `null`, so it doesn't correspond to any of the options and that's why it is blank.

In the case where you don't include `formControlName`, "Selecione" shows because that's the first option in the list.

If you want to treat an empty string as your default/placeholder, then you can do:

```js
this.formEndereco = this.formBuilder.group({
      parentesco: [''],
      estado: [null, [Validators.required]]

    });
```

Also, for the `<option>` element, the `selected` attribute has to be a boolean value, but when using ReactiveForms you don't need to include it because the FormGroup value will automatically set it.

---

Below is an example where you see how a `null` or `""` value will select the corresponding option.

```html
<form [formGroup]="formEndereco">
  <select formControlName="parentesco" id="parentesco" matInput>
    <option [value]="null">Null</option>
    <option value="">Empty</option>
    <option value="foo">Selecione</option>
    <option value="bar">Selecione 2</option>
    <!-- <option *ngFor="let itemParentesco of parentescos" [ngValue]="itemParentesco.name">
      {{itemParentesco.name }}</option> -->
  </select>
</form>
```

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-placeholder',
  templateUrl: './form-placeholder.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form-placeholder.component.css']
})
export class FormPlaceholderComponent implements OnInit {
  formEndereco: FormGroup;
  constructor(formbuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.formEndereco = formbuilder.group({
      parentesco: [], // change to [''] to see empty option selected
      estado: [null, [Validators.required]]
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```